# Getting an error when trying to create a Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shapefile

I have two map plots of 'Total Population' and 'Population Density' created using a shape file. Now, I'm trying to build a shiny app so that I can change from Total Population to Population Density and the plot should change accordingly. When I ran the code, i got following error code:

**Warning: Error in : ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix**

Here's the code that i've been trying to use:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2) #Loading necessary libraries


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("mr",
              label="Type of Plot",
              choices=c("Total Population", "Density"),
              selected="Total Population"),
  plotOutput("curv") #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$curv <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = final.plot==input$mr, 
                   aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Population), 
                   color = "black", size = 0.20) + 
      coord_map()+
      scale_fill_distiller(name="Population", palette = "YlGn")+
      labs(title="Population in Australia")
  }) # Output with the data file and input string to change when input changes.
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

My dataset looks like this:

```
     id     long       lat order  hole piece
1 Ashmore and Cartier Islands 123.1169 -12.25333     1 FALSE     1
2 Ashmore and Cartier Islands 123.1206 -12.25611     2 FALSE     1
3 Ashmore and Cartier Islands 123.1222 -12.25861     3 FALSE     1
4 Ashmore and Cartier Islands 123.1239 -12.25528     4 FALSE     1
5 Ashmore and Cartier Islands 123.1258 -12.25333     5 FALSE     1
6 Ashmore and Cartier Islands 123.1275 -12.25619     6 FALSE     1
                          group Population Density
1 Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1         NA      NA
2 Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1         NA      NA
3 Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1         NA      NA
4 Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1         NA      NA
5 Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1         NA      NA
6 Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1         NA      NA
```

This is stored in the DataFrame called "final.plot". There's values of Population and Density for other states. I was able to create a static visualisation of Population and it looks like this:

[image]

There's a similar one for Density and I'm trying to create Shiny app where i can switch between these two so that the plot changes accordingly. Right now I've tried the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2) #Loading necessary libraries


ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("pop",
              label="Type of Plot",
              choices=c("Population", "Density"),
              selected="Total Population"),
  plotOutput("curv") #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$curv <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = final.plot, 
                   aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = input$pop), 
                   color = "black", size = 0.25) + 
      coord_map()+
      scale_fill_distiller(name="Density", palette = "Spectral")+
      labs(title="Population in Australia")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I'm getting an error saying "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".

**UPDATE 2:** 
Here's the link for the dataset i'm using:
[Dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By0O9WidVSKGNXVVdDI1Tkkwa1E)

Comment: You could try to make a reactive dataset first  (depending on input$mr) and then pass it to ggplot.

Comment: this `data = final.plot==input$mr,` can't probably work and this explains your error message. I suspect other problems (for instance what does `final.plot` is supposed to be, and what `mr` is supposed to do) but that's hard to help if your example is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: Hi, I've edited the post. Would be great of you could look at it and comment on it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the data you want to use to create the plots? You can use the `dput` function to convert your data to a copy paste friendly format

Comment: Hi, i've included a link to my dataset as its too large for me to post it here. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: You can use head() in conjunction with dput() - `dput(head(final.plot,50))` will provide the first 50 rows of your data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a quick look at your code and have a couple of suggestions.

1) When providing your data set you can use the function dput() - this writes a text representation of your data.frame which people answering your question can simply paste into R. For example:

```
dput(final.plot)
```

This will produce text output that I can assign to a dataframe by prefixing `final.plot <-` to the output.  I have recreated your dataframe and used dput() to output it as text below.  Now other users can quickly cut & paste your data:

**Note this dataset is faulty - see below**

```
final.plot <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", class = "factor"), 
                             long = c(123.1169, 123.1206, 123.1222, 123.1239, 123.1258, 123.1275),
                             lat = c(-12.25333, -12.25611, -12.25861, -12.25528, -12.25333, -12.25619),
                             order = 1:6, hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                             piece = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                             group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                             .Label = "Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1", class = "factor"), 
                             Population = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                             Density = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),
                             .Names = c("id", "long", "lat", "order", "hole", "piece", "group", "Population", "Density"),
                             class = "data.frame",
                             row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

The error **"Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"** is caused by two issues.

i) You are passing **NA** in both your Population and Density columns.  The dataframe below adds some (unrealistic) numbers to these columns and the error is removed when I run the plotting code in isolation.

**Corrected Toy Dataset**

```
final.plot <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", class = "factor"), 
                             long = c(123.1169, 123.1206, 123.1222, 123.1239, 123.1258, 123.1275),
                             lat = c(-12.25333, -12.25611, -12.25861, -12.25528, -12.25333, -12.25619),
                             order = 1:6, hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                             piece = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                             group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                               .Label = "Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1", class = "factor"), 
                             Population = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                             Density = c(7, 3, 9, 1, 3, 6)),
                        .Names = c("id", "long", "lat", "order", "hole", "piece", "group", "Population", "Density"),
                        class = "data.frame",
                        row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

ii) When run interactively the error is caused because you are not passing appropriate data to fill in `fill = input$pop`. You should be passing the values from final.plot$Population or final.plot$Density depending on what was selected.  You are instead passing the output of the dropdown box - "Population" or "Density".  This can be corrected using a switch statement within renderPlot:

```
# User input assigns appropriate data to selectedData which can be passed to other functions:
  selectedData <- switch(input$pop, 
                   "Population" = final.plot$Population,
                   "Density" = final.plot$Density)
```

2) It would be helpful if you could provide the code which produced the static map you show in your Update above.  When debugging Shiny code I find it easiest to get the function working non-interactively first and then to incorporate it into Shiny.  I tried to extract your plotting code below but it is not producing the expected results:

```
library(ggplot2) #Loading necessary libraries
library(mapproj)
library(maps)
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = final.plot, 
               [![aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Population), 
               color = "black", size = 0.25) + 
  coord_map()+
  scale_fill_distiller(name="Density", palette = "Spectral")+
  labs(title="Population in Australia")`
```

[image]

3) I am not familiar with plotting data onto maps in R but I believe your app will need to load in library(mapproj) and library(maps) to get the results you need.  Here is all the above put together:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2) #Loading necessary libraries
#I added the two lines below:
library(mapproj) 
library(map)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("pop",
              label="Type of Plot",
              choices=list("Population", "Density"),
              selected="Population"), #NOTE: Total Population changed to Population so that it selects correct default value

  plotOutput("curv") #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
)

server <- function(input, output){

#You will probably want to simply import your dataframe final.plot using read.table etc:      
final.plot <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", class = "factor"), 
                                   long = c(123.1169, 123.1206, 123.1222, 123.1239, 123.1258, 123.1275),
                                   lat = c(-12.25333, -12.25611, -12.25861, -12.25528, -12.25333, -12.25619),
                                   order = 1:6, hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                                   piece = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                   group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                                     .Label = "Ashmore and Cartier Islands.1", class = "factor"), 
                                   Population = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                                   Density = c(7, 3, 9, 1, 3, 6)),
                              .Names = c("id", "long", "lat", "order", "hole", "piece", "group", "Population", "Density"),
                              class = "data.frame",
                              row.names = c(NA, -6L))

  output$curv <- renderPlot({
    #Assign value of selectedData based upon user input:
    selectedData <- switch(input$pop, 
                   "Population" = final.plot$Population,
                   "Density" = final.plot$Density)
    ggplot() +
      geom_polygon(data = final.plot, 
                   aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill =  selectedData), 
                   color = "black", size = 0.25) + 
      coord_map()+
      scale_fill_distiller(name="Density", palette = "Spectral")+
      labs(title="Population in Australia")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now all you need to do is substitute your code which produced the static map shown in your update for the faulty code in renderPlot in your shiny app.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed explanation about the problem Graeme! It's working now. I had to change fill = selectedData and that did the trick! Thanks for taking the time to show this to me.

Comment: I did mark it as the answer. Also, was wondering if i could change the name of the legend according to the choice?

Comment: Thank you Arvind, change the line `scale_fill_distiller(name="Density", palette = "Spectral")+` to  `scale_fill_distiller(name=input$pop, palette = "Spectral")+` this will automatically change the figure legend based upon user input.

Comment: Thanks again Greame! Worked perfectly! Looks sweet now!